# Doctrine Query builder - how to select based on field inside JSON column

Tags: php, json, symfony, mariadb, doctrine

I have a table with a JSON column, it's type longtext (DC2Type:json). This table has an Entity in Doctrine ORM in my Symfony project. I would like to query based on fields inside the JSON column, using the Doctrine query builder I have in a variable `$qb`

How do I do this? Everything I found online says to install a 3rd-party package to enable this. Is there no way to just do it with Doctrine's query builder without installing another package?

One (maybe dumb) workaround I tried was to treat the column as a string, and do...

```
$qb->andWhere("my_data LIKE \"%id:\\\"1,%\"");
```

For example, if I wanted to query the JSON column `my_data` to find the blobs that contain `id":1,` in the string. This fails with a very strange syntax error, and isn't the right way to query a JSON field anyway. HOWEVER, doing the LIKE query directly in SQL client works the way I want, so I also don't know why this is failing in Doctrine.

EDIT: This is MySQL / MariaDB.

Comment: [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/) if you need to patten match on a part. For simple value matches, [JSON_CONTAINS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/) may be sufficient. [Doctrine user defined functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) can help wrap these up.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine Query Language is pretty limited. It covers only the most basic/common SQL functions, which is enough for like 99% use cases, but not all.

If you have a MariaDB version that natively supports JSON (so 10.2 or later) you can use [native functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) to work with the JSON data. (If you don't then your workaround is the only option regardless, with perhaps some additional filtering in the application).

To be able to use these functions in DQL you either need to [define them yourself](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) or indeed use a third party library like [scienta/doctrine-json-functions](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions) (note that it has documentation for how to use it with Symfony, and it's really simple).

If you need just a single extra function and for some reason don't want the whole bundle, you could just copy that single class and use it as your own.

Alternatively you can forgo DQL and write SQL directly, but that way you can't hydrate into objects directly and use other Doctrine magic with the data. But it can be enough for simple use cases.